# Words and phrases

Tags: terminology

What word would you use to describe words and groups of consecutively occurring words, such as:

```
the
it
i am
it is
for a
in the last
why did
```

I would prefer a word that would make sense to even non-linguists if possible.

Comment: Some of these may be words, but most of them, e.g. "i am" aren't phrases.

Comment: @P Elliott That's why I'm asking for a more correct term.

Comment: I'd simply refer to these as 'possible strings of words', or 'possible n-grams of words'. I don't think there's a single word, which isn't very surprising since just talking about possible substrings isn't very useful or insightful generally.

Comment: Exactly. If you have a criterion that fits some strings but not others, you can use that to categorize the strings it identifies (the most useful criteria are generally the ones that identify syntactic constituents). But n-grams at random are just random n-grams.

Comment: I always believed any subset of a sentence longer than a single word was a phrase whether or not they be grammatically complete as verb phrase, noun phrase, or relevant in any other way such as set phrases etc. Just that phrases such as "and the" are of little interest, not that they are not phrases.

Comment: @hippietrail: For syntax, they don't exist, since syntactic rules apply only to constituents. Indeed, syntactic rules **define** constituency. Within that context, _phrase_ always means a constituent phrase, and _string_ is for linear series of words, which may or may not represent anything, and may or may not ever occur in speech.

Comment: @jlawler: Maybe there's a difference between the lay and linguistics senses of *["phrase"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phrase#English)*? ... NOPE seems I've always been wrong. All the dictionaries I can find specify that a phrase must act as a single unit!

Comment: What P Elliot said.

Comment: I think he's asking about N-grams; Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a *phrase* is a constituent that consists of one or more words.

A sequence of one or more words may be called a *string*, since a string is just a sequence of symbols. This definition is used in automata theory and discussion of formal grammars.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them arbitrarily segmented fragments of sentences.